# I am having the following errors when building my FLUTTER Firebase phone authentication application:

Tags: flutter-dependencies

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:firebase_core_web
- package:firebase_auth
- package:firebase
- package:firebase_core_platform_interface
- package:firebase_core
- package:plugin_platform_interface
- package:http_parser
- package:quiver

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if all dependencies can be upgraded
   dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
2. Update to all the latest dependencies
   dart pub upgrade --null-safety
   Ps:you can find in https://codewithandrea.com/articles/migrating-flutter-firebase-app-null-safety/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).